# Conforming an array of enums to Hashable for use as dictionary key

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, enums

I'd like to use an array of custom enums as a dictionary key, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to make the array conform to Hashable. The compiler tells me that [Symbol] doesn't conform to Hashable. What do I have to do to get this to compile?

I messed around with an extension to Array where Element:Symbol, but I couldn't figure out how to add a protocol that way.

```
enum Symbol:Hashable, Equatable {
    case Dot
    case Dash

    var value:Int {
        get {
            switch self {
            case .Dot:          return 0
            case .Dash:         return 1
        }
    }

    var hashValue:Int {
        return self.value
    }  
}

func ==(left: Symbol, right: Symbol) -> Bool {
    return left.value == right.value
}

struct MorseDictionary {
    static let symbolToStringDictionary:[[Symbol]:String] = [
        [.Dot, .Dash]:"A"
    ]
}
```

Comment: what is your ultimate aim - what benefit does using an array as a key provide you ?

Comment: It would probably be less work to come up with a simple work around - you've got a good point. But as a matter of interest I'd still like to see if I can figure out a way to do it with an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### In Swift 2.2 you cannot create an extension restricted to an Array of a specific type

So you cannot conform an Array of `Symbol` to `Hashable` or `Equatable`.
This means you cannot use an Array of Symbol as key in a Dictionary.

Of course you can create an extension making Array (**every array!!**) `Equatable` and `Hashable` but it's a crazy approach since obviously you will never be able to provide a valid implementation.

### However you can follow another approach

First of all your enum can be rewritten this way

```
enum Symbol: Int {
    case Dot = 0, Dash
}
```

Next you'll need a wrapper for an array of Symbol

```
struct Symbols: Hashable, Equatable {
    let value: [Symbol]

    // you can use a better logic here
    var hashValue: Int { return value.first?.hashValue ?? 0 }
}

func ==(left: Symbols, right:Symbols) -> Bool {
    return !zip(left.value, right.value).contains { $0.0 != $0.1 }
}
```

Now you can create your dictionary

```
let dict: [Symbols:String] = [Symbols(value: [.Dot, .Dash]) : "A"]
```

Comment: The wrapper was the trick I was missing! I created a Letter struct that is has an array of Symbols. Works like a charm, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

I have same idea with @appzYourLife. So do not accept my answer. The worth thing here, I have implemented the hash function for Symbols.

```
func ==(left: Symbols, right: Symbols) -> Bool {
    return left.value == right.value
}

enum Symbol: Int {

    case Dot = 0
    case Dash = 1
    case Count = 2
}


struct Symbols: Hashable {

    let symbols: [Symbol]

    init(symbols: [Symbol]) {
        self.symbols = symbols
    }

    var value: Int {

        var sum = 0
        var i = 1

        symbols.forEach({ (s) in

            sum += s.rawValue * i
            i = i * Symbol.Count.rawValue
        })
        return sum
    }

    var hashValue: Int {

        return value % Int(pow(Double(2), Double(Symbol.Count.rawValue)))
    }

}

struct MorseDictionary {

    static let symbolToStringDictionary: [Symbols: String] = [
        Symbols(symbols: [.Dot, .Dash]): "A",
        Symbols(symbols: [.Dash, .Dot]): "B",
        Symbols(symbols: [.Dash, .Dash]): "C",
        Symbols(symbols: [.Dot, .Dot]): "D",
    ]
}
```

Clients's code:

```
MorseDictionary.symbolToStringDictionary[Symbols(symbols: [.Dot, .Dash])]
MorseDictionary.symbolToStringDictionary[Symbols(symbols: [.Dash, .Dot])]
MorseDictionary.symbolToStringDictionary[Symbols(symbols: [.Dash, .Dash])]
MorseDictionary.symbolToStringDictionary[Symbols(symbols: [.Dot, .Dot])]
```

Results in:

```
"A"
"B"
"C"
"D"
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed code, I've got it working now thanks to you appzYourLife. The symbols wrapper was that last piece of the puzzle.